# Generate S_CASE SERIAL_NUM Value in Siebel

Tags: oracle, siebel

I have a Form Applet and it has the Field SERIAL_NUM From the S_CASE Table , but whan i wont to insert a new record i get the Field Empty , how can i ganarate a SERIAL_NUM to insert to the table like the ones in the S_CASE table , is there and Predefult expretion that dose it ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Siebel Object Type Business Component Field`

has attribute named

> Predefault Value

you can provide Siebel valid expression to populate value when creating new record using expression

```
Field: 'Id'
```

or

```
Expr: 'RowIdToRowIdNum ([Id])'.
```

Alternatively you can also write Server side script on

> Siebel Object Type Business Component

in the method

> BusComp_PreNewRecord

to populate customized value when creating new record.

Alternatively you can also use

> Database Trigger

which can also populate customized value to columns and will be available in Business Component Field value.